# How to use String Concatenation in Firebase Cloud Functions to merge all fetched data into a single string?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want fetch all child nodes in a given path from Firebase Realtime Database and which I get using a similar method to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424539/referencing-firebase-database-with-a-variable-and-string-concatenation).

But my main issue is I want to merge then into a single string and I tried out something like this:

```
if(userInput === '/showUsers') {
    const usersRef = `Data/users/` 
    let returnText = `Your users:`

    admin.database().ref(usersRef).on("value", function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (e) {
            const xSnap = e.val()
            const xName = xSnap.Name
            const xId = xSnap.id

            console.log(`${xName} - ${xId}`)
            returnText.concat(`\n${xName}\n${xId}`)
            console.log(returnText)
        })
    })

    return res.status(200).send({
        method: 'sendMessage',
        chat_id,
        reply_to_message_id: messageIdtoReply,
        text: `${returnText}`,
        parse_mode: 'HTML'
    })
}
```

So all the child nodes are getting fetched and they get logged into the console but the `returnText` always remain to it's predefined value. I have to do this because I want to return the data into a Telegram bot so it must be a single string as I cannot return multiple values to telegram bot.

I don't want to use a `for-loop` because those nodes won't be named as 1,2,3 or so on that I can use a loop.

Also **how do I fetch only first 10 users/records** a time so that it won't overflow Telegram message limit?

Expected Output:

[image]

All I want is to get the data into a single message.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with typescript to be honest but I will try to answer your question.

Getting values from firebase is `asynchronous` which means

```
1 const usersRef = `Data/users/` 
2 let returnText = `Your users:`
3
4 admin.database().ref(usersRef).on("value", function (snapshot) {
5   snapshot.forEach(function (e) {
6        const xSnap = e.val()
7        const xName = xSnap.Name
8        const xId = xSnap.id
9
10        console.log(`${xName} - ${xId}`)
11       returnText.concat(`\n${xName}\n${xId}`)
12        console.log(returnText)
13    })
14 })
15 console.log(returnText)
```

If you access `returnText` variable on `line 15` for example it might be executed **before** the above function.

I think you should put this in a function with a call back that gets you returnText when everything finishes executing.

For Example:

```js
function concatResults(cb){
const usersRef = `Data/users/` 
let returnText = `Your users:`

admin.database().ref(usersRef).on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (e) {
        const xSnap = e.val()
        const xName = xSnap.Name
        const xId = xSnap.id

        console.log(`${xName} - ${xId}`)
        returnText.concat(`\n${xName}\n${xId}`)
        console.log(returnText)
    })
    cb(returnText)
})
}
```

Here we have function `concatResults` with a parameter `cb` callback which is called when the foreach finishes it's job.

How to use?
Simply:

```js
concatResults(function(result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

Here we have implemented our callback that will be called after `concatResults` function finishes it's job.

Comment: I have added a return statement in my question about how it will return text to telegram. I tried creating a function but it doesn't seem to be working for me :-( Is there any other way for this?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Can you illustrate more what is the function you are returning to? Why do you need to use `return` ?

Comment: Return is used to send message to a chat using a Telegram bot. As you can see the method `sendMessage`

Comment: Can't you call `res.status(200).send(message)` only without using the return? Return should be used inside a function, I can't get what is the function you are writing inside.

Comment: That's not possible. It leads to code instability. In need use return there or after that code.

Comment: Can you edit the question and write the whole function?

Comment: That's not a function. Just a part of my if-else commands. I've edited and added the if-else to give an idea what it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214118/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-raamyy).

Comment: I've added a screenshot in my question of what I want and let's continue in discussion :D

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the `.concat()` function does not alter the value of any string. It just **returns** the concatenated values ([w3 reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp)). Thus, you should use it as follows:

```
returnText = returnText.concat(`\n${xName}\n${xId}`);
```

Also, due to the single threaded nature of JS, in order to return the concatenated text you should perform the return inside the `admin.database().ref(usersRef).on("value", function (snapshot) { ... }` block or better yet, use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406966/12163274)